# how to change table command results and add p-value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have such data

```
AE=structure(list(TRTGROUP_E1_C18 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), AETERM = c("increase in lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"increase in abs. lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. neutrophils", 
"decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. monocytes", "decrease in monocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in hemoglobin", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"decrease in abs. monocytes ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I want to see the ratio of different types of adverse events for each group.
I use `table(AE)` and the output format is not in the form of a table that I would like.
I need this format
[image]

N=number people in group.
`0(0,0%) - Absolute value (and percentage)`  and also p-value via chisq.test(table(AE$RTGROUP, dat$AETERM)) for each `ae`.
How to get such desired table?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `table1()` from the package `table1`.

Since your calculation of p-value includes some columns that are not present in `AE`, I'll ignore it.

```
library(table1)

table1(~AETERM | TRTGROUP_E1_C18, data = AE)
```

[image: AE_table1]

Comment: how to add chi-sqaure statistics?